# connecting to redistogo gives error:-

Tags: connection, redis, redistogo

Trying to connect to redis thru the following redistogo credentials gives  error.

```
var redisClient = require('redis').createClient({
    host: 'birdeye.redistogo.com',
    port: 1222,
    db: 'redistogo',
    pass: '012345c2f2402f7878588dd5fb129'
  });
```

Getting error:-

```
Error Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:[object Object] failed - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
var redisClient = require('redis').createClient( 1234, 'birdeye.redistogo.com', {detect_buffers: true});
```

connects.

> redis.createClient(port, host, options)
>
> Create a new client connection. port defaults to 6379 and host
>   defaults to 127.0.0.1. If you have redis-server running on the same
>   computer as node, then the defaults for port and host are probably
>   fine. options in an object with the following possible properties:

from [node_redis](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis)